# generic type conforming to a protocol in Swift

Tags: generics, types, swift, protocols

Is it possible to require that specific instantiations of generic types conform to a protocol in Swift?

For example, say I have a generic type called `Thing<T>`. I want `Thing<Int>` to conform to a certain protocol, but not `Thing<T>`.

Comment: sounds like some sort of witchcraft you want

Comment: `Thing<T where if T : A then T : B>`; `Thing<T where T : B when T : A>`; `Thing<T where T : A ?? B>` Those don't work, but that's something like you would like to write, correct? I think the closest you can get right now is checking the conformance in an failable initializer and returning nil when the conformance doesn't match your requirements.

Comment: You're asking for [ConstraintKinds](https://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.4.1/html/users_guide/constraint-kind.html) which are a feature of higher-kinded type systems.  Considering we don't even have regular kinds, let alone type families, there really isn't a way around this.

Comment: In swift don't we have automatic protocol conformance. Where if you implement all of the methods

Comment: What do you want to do with the constrained protocols to Thing<Int> ?

Answer (score 3):

Well, it might not be too onerous, and it might be obvious enough that you've ignored it, but you could make a 'specific instantiation of a generic type' - as:

```
class ThingOfInt : Thing<Int>, SpecialIntProtocol {
 // implement SpecialIntProtocol (if it isn't already 
 // implemented in an extension)
}
```

or with a bit more generality:

```
class IntThing<T:IntegerType> : MyThing<T>, SpecialIntProtocol {
}
```

Comment: It's unfortunate that this isn't a general purpose answer, since the type I want to constrain is an `enum`, and hence can't be subclassed. As in, "If the enum has type `Int`, make it conform to protocol `X`"

Comment: This is another nice and correct answer... yet to a different question :-(

Answer (score 2):

In **Swift 2.0** you can extend protocols and types

When you extend it you can add a generic `where` constraints. Only types that matches that rule will be able to use that functionality

**Example**:

```
public struct Thing<T> {
  let x: T
}

extension Thing where T : IntegerType {
  func giveMeInt () -> T {
    return x
  }
}

let a = Thing<Int>(x: 10)
a.giveMeInt()

let b = Thing(x: 10.1)
//b.giveMeInt() // Error
```

This way you can add an extra functionality to `Thing<Int>` type

I don't know a way to conform to a protocol in the extension, but it doesn't make much sense.

**Limitation:** Generic `where T :` can be used with protocols and classes, that's why we can't specify Int there

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't answer his question because he want Thing to conform to specific protocols in relation to T.

Comment: I know, just wanted to show that it's possible.
Also I think you should watch Protocol Oriented programming WWDC15 session. It does make sense to add a protocol conformation in the extension to a specific generic

Comment: No, you did not show **it's** possible. You only showed that something is possible that is not really related to the question. The question was about making a generic type conform to a protocol and in your answer there isn't even a protocol, nowhere. This is a nice answer... but to a completely different question. Making an object conform through a protocol by extension is something the cfisher probably knows, he wanted to know how this is done for generics.

Answer (score -3):

You can do something like using the `where` keyword and pass a condition afterwords. Saw this under Where Clauses section  https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Generics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH26-XID_275

```
class Thing<T : SomeProtocol where reflect(T).summary != "Int"> {
    ...
}
```

Comment: The `where` clause in type constraints only accepts `:` and `==` conditions and are evaluated at compile time. (`reflect(T).summary != "Int"` is a runtime expression)