# In Swift, how to extend constrained generic struct to conform to a protocol?

Tags: swift, generics, struct, protocols

I want all Arrays that contain HeartRate elements to conform to the Encodable protocol. Something like:

`extension (Array where Element: HeartRate): Encodable {}` (this doesn't compile obviously).

This answer has a solution for generic classes, but this doesn't work for me since Array is a struct:  [generic type conforming to a protocol in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26357866/generic-type-conforming-to-a-protocol-in-swift)

Comment: It's not currently possible, but will be possible in a future version of Swift – see [SE-0143](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0143-conditional-conformances.md).

Comment: Please read the section on Conditional Conformances https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/docs/GenericsManifesto.md It will be quite a long time before we get this, I suspect.

Comment: yes, duplicate, thank you